# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease' - this meassage appears when i tried to build AppBundle in Android Studio for Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, build, apk

I have completed editing the entire code, but when I tried to build appbundle, it did not work.

Please note-

1. Flutter is installed in my laptop.
   2.I have created bin folder in Environment variables>Path>C\users\user_name\documents\flutter\bin
2. Java script is installed in my laptop
3. I have disabled my antivirus

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Execution always keep failing,this message appears.

Answer (score 0):

[image: missing icon]

The error in the console states that you have used icon `Icons.pie_chart_outlined`, which does not exits. Possible replacement can be `Icons.pie_chart_outline_outlined` or `Icons.pie_chart_outline`

Comment: So if I remove this entire line from my Source code then will i be able to solve my problem? or do you think removing this line may cause some other problem?